# Having problems with a small array

Tags: java, arrays

trying to learn and practice arrays but I have a problem with this small example. Can someone please help me please? Thank you

```
public class Homework1{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] anArray={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    System.out.println(anArray.length);
    int min=0;
    int max=0;

    for(int i=0; i<anArray.length; i++){
        if(anArray[i].compareTo(anArray[min]) < 0)
            min=i;

        if(anArray[i].compareTo(anArray[max]) > 0)
            max=i;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(min);
}
}
```

And I am getting this error message:

```
int cannot be dereferenced
        if(anArray[i].compareTo(anArray[min]) < 0)
int cannot be dereferenced
        if(anArray[i].compareTo(anArray[max]) > 0)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompareTo will not work with Premitive type. You can use comparator operator.

```
public class TestArray  {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
int[] anArray={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

System.out.println(anArray.length);
int min=0;
int max=0;

for(int i=0; i<anArray.length; i++){
    if(anArray[i] <(anArray[min]) )
        min=i;

    if(anArray[i]>(anArray[max]) )
        max=i;
}

System.out.println(max);
System.out.println(min);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the expression `anArray[i]` is `int`. `int` is a primitive type, which means it's not a "real" object. You can't call methods (like `compareTo()`) on primitive types.

However, you can call methods on the type `Integer`, which is the "boxing" type that corresponds to `int`. (Boxing types are types you use as wrappers for primitive types when you need to treat them as objects.)

Just use the regular comparison operators for integral types:

```
if (anArray[i] < anArray[min]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the main reason one might *need* to treat a primitive as an object is for use with generics (e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>`). Java's generic type system does not allow primitives (unlike C++ templates), and since generics weren't an original feature, they decided to use primitive datatypes (in contrast to, for example, Ruby, where numeric constants are just instances of numeric classes (e.g. `4` is an instance of the `FixNum` class)).

Comment: @jpm Aren't Ruby's `FixNum`s kind of special? I seem to recall they're implemented as tagged object handles, so you actually use the "primitive" value, but the interpreter handles them specially to make them behave like real objects.

Comment: @Inerdial That's quite possible. I haven't really looked into the implementation, but even so, that would seem to just be an optimization. The net effect is approximately the same for the developer, though.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `int`s are not objects, and thus comparison is done with via operators (<, >, ==, etc.). If you want to use compareTo, you'll have to use and array of `Integer`s.

Comment: Nice comment, I am writing it down.

Answer (score 1):

To use the method `compareTo()` make your array an `Integer` list, not primitive `int` list.
Change this line

`int[] anArray={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

to this line:

`Integer[] anArray={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

Compiling errors will disappear.

Comment: He isn't calling `compareTo()` on the array, but instead, the `int` elements of the array.

Comment: hu! interesting, I thought that 'int' and 'Integer' would do exactly the same thing. Thank you

Comment: @Bartg review your accepted answer, if this is better for you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specifically cast / box your int to an Integer in order to use compareTo.

E.g.

```
if (((Integer)anArray[i]).compareTo(anArray[min]) < 0)
```

But as stated in another answer, you probably want to just do the comparison directly on the int using the standard operators <, >, etc, instead of using compareTo at all.

Answer (score 1):

The int is a primitive type and as such cannot be dereferenced. Only reference types can be dereferenced. The dot (.) is the dereferencing operator. You are attempting to treat the primitive int like an object. You can use the comparison operators such as < and > and == to compare primitive integers.

Comment: Thank you, your comments are so important, I am writing it down.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to find the minimal and maximal value,
anArray[min] or anArray[max] in this case are useless, as you get the value of the min/max index.
the correct way of doing this is:

```
if(anArray[i]>max)
    max = anArray[i];

if(anArray[i]<min)
    min = anArray[i];
```

Comment: deferenciation means treating a data type as an object, int is not an object, Integer is.